# Micronaut: Proper logging of "uncaught" Exceptions to not appear on System.err

Tags: exception, micronaut, error-logging

I've a question regarding capture of "uncaught" exceptions, which appears with stack trace on `System.err`, **circumventing logging configuration**: All the other log messages appear properly formatted on `System.out` (JSON-formatted in my case). But this doesn't happen with Exceptions and stack traces "logged" to System.err!

I've recognized this to happen under at least two circumstances:

- Asynchronous execution of tasks (HTTP requests in my case) via `ExecutorService` (as mentioned in ["Scheduled Tasks" chapter](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#scheduling)). I've added `@Retryable` annotation to the method; but after all retries fail, "final" Exception thrown by last unsuccessful retry appears on `System.err` with its stack trace (the other ones thrown by earlier failed retries do **not** appear, seems they are caught by retry "mechanism" under the hood).
- With Exceptions thrown by failed Health indicators (they are implemented by subclassing `AbstractHealthIndicator`).

I've tried implementing my own `TaskExceptionHandler`, replacing the default one (also mentioned in ["Scheduled Tasks" chapter](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#scheduling)); and/or by adding `System.setErr(System.out)` in `main` method before building/setup of Micronaut Application Context. But nothing seems to help as my test cases attest.

Have I missed a chapter in Micronaut's documentation?
Thanks for any hints.

Regards

Christian

Comment: "Have I missed a chapter in Micronaut's documentation?" - I don't know if you have or not but is it the case that what you want is when uncaught exceptions are encountered that you would like them written to stderr and you want something to JSON format the log entry?

Comment: Hi Jeff, my goal is to have these errors/messages logged just like the other ones: With mentioned issues Exceptions are simply spit out to System.err ignoring all logging framework configs (like to format them as JSON, which brings e.g. one log line per message, not stack traces getting spread over many lines).

Answer (score 0):

My wager is that Micronaut doesn't provide tools for setting a global uncaught exception handler because that's governed by the wider JRE. We've solved the problem in a few of our services with [`Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) by doing something like this at application startup:

```java
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> logger.error("Uncaught exception", e));
```